# Unable to use \tag in split equation

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations, align, split

So I was attempting to tag a equation in a split mode

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \dot x &= Ax + Bu\\
    y &= Cx + Du \tag*{Nobody Knows what these equations mean}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I am getting an error that says \tag is not allowed.

Help.
[image]

Sample Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Preamble

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{SOS}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
{\bfseries New Section}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \dot x &= Ax + Bu\\
    y &= Cx + Du \tag*{Nobody Knows what these equations mean}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`split` assumes (as other math environments defined in `amsmath`/`mathtools` package for use inside math environments) that numbering will provide outer math environment (for whole `split`). In your case is this is `equation`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\tag*{Nobody Knows what these equations mean}
\begin{split}
    \dot x &= Ax + Bu\\
    y &= Cx + Du 
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you like to tag particular row of your equations, than you need to change math environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\dot x &= Ax + Bu   \notag\\
y &= Cx + Du        \tag*{Nobody Knows what these equations mean}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:**
As egreg pointed in his comment below, the above result also can be obtained with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \dot x &= Ax + Bu\\
    y &= Cx + Du    \tag*{Nobody Knows what these equations mean}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Remark:**
as pointed  Gustavo Mezzetti in his comment,  the `\tag*` command is not meant for adding comments to equations: other, and well-known means are available for this. its purpose is tagged equation with some symbol or name, which replace equation numbering.

Comment: In the second example you can use `align*` so `\notag` is not needed.

Comment: I think someone should remark that the `\tag*` command is not meant for adding comments to equations: other, and well-known means are available for this.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, now I owe an explanation about these “other, and well-known means”.  Here is an example, that also illustrates how to label the various equations, if this is needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

Comment vertically centered w.r.t.\ the two equations:
\begin{align*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \dot{x} &= Ax+Bu  \\
        y &= Cx+Du
    \end{aligned}
    && \text{Nobody Knows what these equations mean!}
\end{align*}

The same thing, but with an equation number:
\begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
        \dot{x} &= Ax+Bu  \\
        y &= Cx+Du
    \end{aligned}
    && \text{Nobody Knows what these equations mean!}
    \label{eq:some-label}
\end{align}
And a reference to \eqref{eq:some-label}.

It's even simpler if the comment pertains to a single line:
\begin{align*}
    \dot{x} &= Ax+Bu  \\
    y &= Cx+Du && \text{Nobody Knows what this equation means!}
\end{align*}

The same thing with equation numbers\ldots
\begin{align}
    \dot{x} &= Ax+Bu \label{eq:one}  \\
    y &= Cx+Du && \text{Nobody Knows what this equation means!}
                \label{eq:two}
\end{align}
\ldots and correspondinge references \eqref{eq:one} and~\eqref{eq:two}.

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: (+1), good examples about how to add comments to equation ...